# Подписание файла ЭЦП

Tags: криптография, openssl, decrypt

форумчани. Существует пара ключей(public и private, созданы не мною) и пароль для расшифровки приватного ключа, всё это лежит в двух файлах Key-6.dat и Key-11.dat. Нужно подписать файл данными ключами. Как это сделать, без понятия. Пытался воспользоваться командами `openssl dgst -md5 –out f.txt.sign –sign sasha.pr.pem f.txt`, но понимаю, что это сюда не клеится. Требуется только одна функция - подписание. Ключи могу предоставить. Как подписать?

Comment: Точно нужно при помощи хэша md5 подписывать?

Comment: Это просто пример который я использовал. Думаю, что md5 сюда не клеится